# Can neuromuscular electrical stimulation be used as a low-cost alternative to mechanical breathing

Tags: neurology, covid-19, pulmonology, electricity, mechanical-ventilation

It is speculated that because of COVID-19 pandemic there may be shortage of intensive care equipment (mechanical breathers) causing deaths.

Though IDK what is so costly in these mechanical breathers except market regulation and oligopolisation, it may make sense to start producing low-cost alternatives. Also some people hint that it may be because some materials must be not carcinogenic, but nebulizers are also pumps, and they are cheap enough.

So I guessed that in some cases electric muscular stimulatiin can help. And it has benefit that the muscles actually work.

Indeed, here is https://patents.google.com/patent/US5911218A, that has just expired (and even if not, **** patent trolls), and some papers on testing that techniques on people [1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6079614/).

It looks like this tech can be rapidly manufactured in the case of shortage.

So I wonder, are there any critical side effects preventing this tech from replacing mechanical ventilation?